# speed up my awk command?  Answer must be awk :)

Tags: bash, split, awk, gsub

I have some awk code that is running really slow. The format of my file is tab delimited 5 column ASCII.   I am operating on column 5 to get a count of appropriate characters to alter the value in column 4.

Example input line:

> 10      5134832 N       28      Aaaaa*AAAAaAAAaAAAAaAAAA^]a^]a^Fa^]a

If I find any "^" in $5 I want to not count it, or the following character. 
Then I want to find out how many characters are ">" or "<" or "*" and remove them from the count.  I'm guessing using a gsub, and 3 splits is less than ideal, especially since column 5 can occasionally be a very very long string.

```
awk '{l=$4; if($5~/>/ || $5~/</ || $5~/*/ )  {gsub(/\^./,"");l-=split($5,a,"<")-1;l-=split($5,a,">")-1;l-=split($5,a,"*")-1}
```

If the code runs successfully on the line above, l will be 27.

I am omitting the surrounding parts of the command to try and focus on the part I have a question about.

So, what is the best step to make this run faster?

Answer (score 1):

Well as I see, your `gsub` pattern will not work, as the `/` was not closed. Anyway, if I get it correctly and you want the character count of `$5` without some characters, I'd go with:

```
count=length(gensub("[><A-Z^]","","g",$5))
```

You should list your skippable characters between `[` and `]`, and do not start with `^`!

Comment: Thanks Zsolt.   The added trick is that along with omitting some single characters I want to omit any character pairs of "^[A-Z]"

Comment: What you mean by character pairs?

Comment: I edited the question to show what I mean by character pairs. Above I want to omit "^]" and "^F" from my counting.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guess:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"}
    {
        str = $5
        gsub(/\^.|[><*]/, "", str)
        l = length(str)
    }
'
```

Comment: So generally, gsub on multiple charaters should be faster than multiple splits?

Comment: @lonestar21, don't know, try it and see. With multiple splits, awk has to create multiple arrays in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use `awk`, or will this work instead?

```
cut -f 5 < $file | grep -v '^[A-Z]' | tr -d '<>*\n' | wc -c
```

Translation:

- Extract the 5th field from the tab-delimited `$file`.
- Remove all fields starting with a capital letter.
- Remove the characters `<`, `>`, `*`, and newlines.
- Count the remaining characters.

Comment: I kinda need to use awk since this is part of a larger awk command.

Comment: Ok.  But no fair changing the specs in the question _after_ answers are posted!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo "10 5134832 N 28 Aaaaa*AAAAaAAAaAAAAaAAAA^]a^]a^Fa^]a" |
awk '/[><*^]/{t=$5;gsub(/[><*]|[\^]./,"",t);$4=length(t)}1' 
10 5134832 N 27 Aaaaa*AAAAaAAAaAAAAaAAAA^]a^]a^Fa^]a
```

if you want to show the amended fifth field:

```
 awk '/[><*^]/{gsub(/[><*]|[\^]./,"",$5);$4=length($5)}1'
```